# How to lose Stack Overflow reputation gained from a specific question?

Tags: support, questions, reputation

How can I lose all the reputation gained because of a question that I asked previously?

My friend initially asked a query using my account and I don't want the reputation gained through that question. Is there a way to make that question anonymous and lose the reputation the question earned me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can request to have the question [disassociated from your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-ccwiki). Use the [contact us link](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) at the bottom of each page to ask for this.

I'm not sure if the reputation will be deducted *immediately*, but I think this will at least trigger a scheduled recalculation of your reputation (see [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14200/self-instigated-rep-recalc/71678#comment805767_71678)).

Comment: In the mail content section I just need to mentioned the question link and request to disassociate? Is that enough? This will deduct the reputation and privileges gained too?

Comment: Yes, that's enough.